# Getting permission denied error accessing mount point in azure synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I tried different docs in google.still I getting Same Error message
I am using azure synapse with ADLS gen2

Could anyone provide me any suggestions. How to solve this problem?

Comment: hi @Cristena Melendez, Please edit and provide error message and code block

Comment: Hi This is my error message PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied :<file path>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission denied [errno 13] occurred when you try to access path without having the enough permission. Please make sure to check whether you have all permission.

Otherwise go to **Azure Storage Account** -> **Access control (IAM)** -> **+Add role assignment** as Storage blob data contributor.

[image: Ref1]

**Syntax:**

```
#Mounting ADLS Gen2
mssparkutils.fs.mount(
    "abfss://<container>@<Storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net",
    "/<mount_folder>",
    {"linkedService":"Azure_datalake_Gen2"}
)
```

[image: Ref2]

For more information refer this [**GitHub Link**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api.md)